# How to get info video (redtube)

Tags: php

My script:

```
function redtube_search($search, $page) {
    $feedurl = 'http://api.redtube.com/?data=redtube.Videos.searchVideos&output=json&search='.$search.'&thumbsize=big&page='.$page;
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 15;
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$feedurl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $content = json_decode($data,true);
    return $content;
}

$videos = redtube_search('teen',1);

print_r($videos);
```

How to assign a variable: title, thumbs, duration?

I would like to process the downloaded content.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
foreach($videos['videos'] as $v){
   // title, thumbs, duration?
    $title = $v['video']['title'];
    $thumb = $v['video']['thumb'];
    $duration = $v['video']['duration'];

    echo "Title: {$title}<br> Duration: {$duration}<br> Thumb: {$thumb}<br>"; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! how to display all of them?now displays only one